# Creating a custom module in node for GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I'm currently following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/graphql/graphql_environment_setup.htm) tutorial in an attempt to learn GraphQL with React but I'm getting the following error when trying to run `npm start`:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'notarealdb'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/Workspace/intro-to-graphql/db.js
- /Users/user/Workspace/intro-to-graphql/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Workspace/intro-to-graphql/db.js:1:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/user/Workspace/intro-to-graphql/db.js',
    '/Users/user/Workspace/intro-to-graphql/server.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm completely new to GraphQL, so I think what's going on here

```
const { DataStore } = require('notarealdb');

const store = new DataStore('./data');
```

is that we're creating a new DataStore that we interact with in place of interacting with a traditional database, and we're replacing `notarealdb` with a name that maps to what is found in `./data`. I guess `notarealdb` has to map to something, but the tutorial doesn't mention what it is.

Does anyone know exactly what this tutorial means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [an actual npm module can install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/notarealdb).

Comment: That worked, thanks! Curious how it wasn't one of the dependencies, that certainly would have been helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can install notarealdb by using this code

`npm install notarealdb@0.2.2`

And if error comes then use

`sudo npm install notarealdb@0.2.2`

Comment: Thanks mate! I was having the same error your answer worked for me